# How to call activity2 after activity1 in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to execute the login_activity first, then the form_activity like this.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Check Login
    val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)

    // After login, call FormActivity
    val intent2 = Intent(this, FormActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent2)

}
```

My problem is that if I run this, the app directly opens FormActivity, however, if I comment out the call to FormActivity, then the LoginActivity opens successfully.

What I need is to open the FormActivity *only* after the LoginActivity returns successfully.

Comment: well just put this 2nd intent in the onCreate method of Form Activity

Comment: if you are trying to check that if your user is logged in already or not! probably you should read the concept on making sessions using preference storage

Comment: Then you need to start the form activity after the login is a success and not immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `startActivityForResult()`. Compared to `startActivity()`, `startActivityForResult` takes an additional integer argument as a request code which identifies your request to the activity. You'll also need to over-ride the `onActivityResult()` method to handle the called Activity finishing

Example of starting an activity for a result:

```
static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

public void foo(){
    Intent someIntent = new Intent(YOUR_INTENT_HERE); 
    startActivityForResult(someIntent, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Handle the result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE){
        bar();
    }
}
```

You use the request code as well as the Intent called `data` to handle whatever data results from launching the other Activity

In Kotlin:

```
companion object{
    private const val MY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
}

fun foo(){
    val someIntent = Intent(YOUR_INTENT_HERE)
    startActivityForResult(someIntent, MY_RESULT_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?){
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE){
        bar()
    }
}
```

For more info:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#ReceiveResult

Answer (score 1):

You need to `startActivityForResult` . Read here : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

A very good example can be found here: [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: This is the correct answer, but could be more helpful with a small example.

Comment: Added an example link.